# Why doesn't 'sudo -E' preserve the function environment variables exported by export -f?

Tags: bash, sudo, environment-variables, function

In script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

func(){
  echo "I am here a func."
}

export -f func
export variable="I am here a variable"

sudo -E bash -c "func ; echo $variable"
```

And the output came:

```
bash: func: command not found
I am here a variable
```

1. WHY?
2. Is there any solution to let me call a function [which declared in script.sh] within a newborn shell by sudo?

Actually I know a method like :

```
#!/bin/bash

func(){
  echo "I am here a func."
}

FUNC=$(declare -f func)
export variable="I am here a variable"

sudo -E bash -c "$FUNC; func ; echo $variable"
```

But I think it's too heavy, because I have to register every function in this way.

Answer (score 7):

After `export -f func` I can see the following in the environment:

```
$ env | grep func
BASH_FUNC_func%%=() …
```

Bash exports functions as variables with names like `BASH_FUNC_foo%%` and values starting with `()`. I believe before [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)) names were without any prefix (`foo=() …`). Apple prefix seems to be `__BASH_FUNC<`. In any case the value starts with `()`.

`sudo` tries to be very careful with these names and with the whole environment in general. Imagine you are allowed to run a Bash script with `sudo` and nothing but the script. Imagine the script legitimately uses `cat`. By exporting a shell function named `cat` you could effectively change the script and run arbitrary code.

You could do the same by using your own `$PATH` (and [there are ways to do it](https://superuser.com/a/1551572/432690); but there are also ways for the admin for not letting you do it). Or if you managed to use `$LD_PRELOAD` (not so easy, see [`man 5 sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/sudoers.man/) where it mentions `LD_`).

Let's go back to exported shell functions. First of all, when I run `sudo -V` as root (`sudo sudo -V` as regular user), a part of the output is like:

```
Environment variables to remove:
        *=()*
```

Or maybe:

```
Environment variables to remove:
        __BASH_FUNC<*
        BASH_FUNC_*
```

depending on the version of `sudo`, I think.

I can remove these patterns from the list with the following line in `sudoers` (but don't do this yet, read the whole answer first):

```
Defaults       env_delete -= "*=()* BASH_FUNC_* __BASH_FUNC<*"
```

And I can even add them to the "preserve" list (also don't):

```
Defaults        env_keep += "*=()* BASH_FUNC_* __BASH_FUNC<*"
```

Still it will not necessarily make your exported function work with `sudo`. The reason is the pattern of `*=()*` might be hardcoded, some versions of `sudo` reject variables with values starting with `()`. This behavior evolved. Available solutions depend on `sudo` version you have.

From [`man 5 sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.28/sudoers.man.html#Command_environment):

> Command environment
>
> Since environment variables can influence program behavior, `sudoers` provides a means to restrict which variables from the user's environment are inherited by the command to be run. There are two distinct ways sudoers can deal with environment variables.
>
> By default, the `env_reset` option is enabled. […] The `HOME`, `MAIL`, `SHELL`, `LOGNAME` and `USER` environment variables are initialized based on the target user and the `SUDO_*` variables are set based on the invoking user. Additional variables, such as `DISPLAY`, `PATH` and `TERM`, are preserved from the invoking user's environment if permitted by the `env_check` or `env_keep` options. This is effectively a whitelist for environment variables. […] Environment variables with a value beginning with `()` are removed unless both the name and value parts are matched by `env_keep` or `env_check`, as they may be interpreted as functions by the bash shell. Prior to version 1.8.11, such variables were always removed.
>
> If, however, the `env_reset` option is disabled, any variables not explicitly denied by the `env_check` and `env_delete` options are inherited from the invoking process. In this case, `env_check` and `env_delete` behave like a blacklist. Prior to version 1.8.21, environment variables with a value beginning with `()` were always removed. Beginning with version 1.8.21, a pattern in `env_delete` is used to match bash shell functions instead. Since it is not possible to blacklist all potentially dangerous environment variables, use of the default `env_reset` behavior is encouraged.
>
> Environment variables specified by `env_check`, `env_delete`, or `env_keep` may include one or more `*` characters which will match zero or more characters. No other wildcard characters are supported.
>
> By default, environment variables are matched by name. However, if the pattern includes an equal sign (`=`), both the variables name and value must match. For example, a bash shell function could be matched as follows:
>
> ```
> env_keep += "BASH_FUNC_my_func%%=()*"
> ```
>
> Without the `=()*` suffix, this would not match, as bash shell functions are not preserved by default.

As you can see `env_reset` is important. You most likely have it enabled. Note the whole point of the `-E` option (`sudo -E`) is to disable `env_reset` on demand.

---

In my Kubuntu 18.04.3 LTS I have `sudo` in the version 1.8.21. By default it places `*=()*` on the list of variables to remove. This line in `sudoers` makes it stop:

```
Defaults       env_delete -= "*=()*"
```

Then `sudo -E` will preserve any exported shell function. **This is my primary answer.**

---

In my Debian 9 `sudo` is in the version 1.8.19. By default it places `BASH_FUNC_*` and `__BASH_FUNC<*` on the list of variables to remove. Removing these entries doesn't work because the tool almost always rejects variables with values beginning with `()` anyway; this behavior seems to be hardcoded.

The manual for this version gives some clues. I found one solution:

```
Defaults       env_keep += "BASH_FUNC_func%%=()*"
```

Then `sudo` *without* `-E` will preserve this particular shell function (`func`) if exported. Disadvantages (or maybe advantages in some circumstances):

- this doesn't work with `sudo -E`, so I cannot simply keep the rest of environment on demand;
- I need to explicitly specify the whole name of the variable, without wildcards; `BASH_FUNC_*%%=()*`, `BASH_FUNC_*` or `*=()*` will not work.

This approach works in 1.8.21 as well.

---

According to the manual, prior to version 1.8.11 variables starting with `()` were always removed. If your `sudo` is that old then there is no solution other than the trick you used in the question (or similar).

---

Notes:

- Do not edit `sudoers` like any other file; use `visudo`. Other precautions just in case:

  - Start a separate "spare" shell as root (`sudo -i`). If you do something stupid with `sudoers` in your main shell, you will still be able to act as root without relying on the file.
  - When connecting via SSH, use `tmux` or `screen` before spawning the elevated shell. If you do something stupid with `sudoers` and (accidentally) the connection fails, the elevated shell will wait for your regular user to reattach, instead of exiting.
  - Make a backup copy of the file first (`cp -a`), especially if you're going to experiment with it.
  - When you think you're done, make sure you can gain the root access anew before you exit the "spare" elevated shell.
- Even if you are the only user and there is little point in hardening `sudo` against tricks that allow sudoers to run arbitrary code (because you can `sudo` freely and thus you can run arbitrary code anyway without tricks, and you want it this way), think twice before you allow too much. Allowing `sudo` to preserve any shell function may make it easy for you to shoot yourself in the foot; not necessarily now, but in the future.

Comment: So the answer to `WHY?` is that "Allowing `sudo` to preserve any shell function may make it easy for you to shoot yourself in the foot" ?

Comment: @aafulei Ah, the deeper "why?". See the revision 3 [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/549329/revisions).

Comment: Thanks for your revision "Imagine the script legitimately uses cat. By exporting a shell function named cat you could effectively change the script and run arbitrary code." It's a convincing example.