# How do I make a .bashrc shell function interactive?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

```
eshark() {
ssh root@$1 'tcpdump -i $2 port 5060 -vv -s0 -Uw - ' | sudo tshark --interface - --print -w $3.pcapng
}
```

When I run this, on a Linux machine, it says `capturing on stdin` whereas when I run it in the terminal, it asks for the host authentication, I provide it, then the capture starts.

I do realize I may need to run this in the root `.bashrc`, because I don't think you can `sudo` in a `.bashrc` function, but... one problem at a time.

Comment: though the solution is simply (set up key-based authentication in your SSH), this really is not something you want to run in your .bashrc. Also, your local `sudo` is completely superfluous.

Comment: So, taking a step back: you just want to have a program that when you log in automatically shows you a live packet dump from a different computer. Why not simply write that as a script?

Comment: @terdon Executing a function via `sudo`? No. Note that the user is single-quoting the `$2` and that there is no indication what the difference between "running this on a Linux machine" and "running this in the terminal" is (or even what "this" is). The `sudo` is a red herring and we don't know what the actual issue is.

Comment: Oh man. Sorry about that, of course @Kusalananda is absolutely right and you cannot run user-defined functions via `sudo` (not without [jumping through several hoops](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/269078/22222) and [opening yourself to security issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/549329/22222)). I was thinking there may have been an issue with `ssh` consuming `stdin` which is why the password prompt wasn't appearing, but I think I was just completely wrong. I read the question as the command working when executed directly but failing when used as a function.